# Swift 3 - Floating Button over UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, floating-action-button

I created a floating button by [this first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725528/swift-floating-plus-button-over-tableview-using-the-storyboard/41478655). It works but when the `UICollectionView`launched, the floating button still square and became circle after all datas appear (after loadAPI finished running).

Here's my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.roundButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    self.roundButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)
    self.roundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.ButtonClick(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(self.roundButton)

    self.loadAPI(Page: 1)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    roundButton.layer.cornerRadius = roundButton.layer.frame.size.width/2
    roundButton.backgroundColor = green
    roundButton.clipsToBounds = true
    roundButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"ic_add_white_2x"), for: .normal)
    roundButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        roundButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        roundButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        roundButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
        roundButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
    ])
}

@IBAction func ButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton){
 //print("clicked")
}
```

I need the button being a circle since the `UICollectionView` first appears. Can somebody help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Since you do `roundButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60), roundButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)`, you know that its widht/height will be 60. Then, just do `roundButton.layer.cornerRadius = 60.0/2` from the start at viewDidLoad and all the other infos like backgroundColor, etc, not in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: @Larme wow that's perfect! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// update this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.roundButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    self.roundButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)
    self.roundButton.layer.cornerRadius = roundButton.layer.frame.size.width/2
    self.roundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.ButtonClick(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(self.roundButton)

    self.loadAPI(Page: 1)
}
```